# Functions not being Called in C

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array

Hi i am trying to use Functions to output the contents of an array through ascending order but the Function is incorrectly working to my specific outcome, specifically inside the Bubblesort Function Does anyone know why?

- I have been trying to figure this out for numerous hours, so would be great to get some emphasis.
  The comments towards the bottom are for the descending order output.
  [current output of Ascending Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9aGd.jpg)

  ```
  int main() 
  {
     int arrayHeight, array[100][2], xCoord, yCoord, i;
     printf ("***** Bubble Sort ***** \n");
     printf("How many items of data do you wish to enter? ");
     scanf("%d",&arrayHeight);
     for(i=0; i<arrayHeight; i++)
     {
        printf("Please enter in the X coordinate: ");
        scanf("%d", &xCoord);
        printf("Please enter in the Y coordinate: ");
        scanf("%d", &yCoord);
        array[i][0] = xCoord;
        array[i][1] = yCoord;
     }
     DisplayArray(array,arrayHeight);
     Bubblesort (array, arrayHeight);
  }

  int DisplayArray(int array[100][2],int arrayHeight, int swap) 
  {
     /*Displaying Array elements*/
     int i, j;
     printf("\n The 2-D Array contains : \n");
     for(i=0; i<arrayHeight; i++)
     {
        printf("[%d][%d]\n\r", array[i][0], array[i][1]);
     }
  }  

  int BubbleSort(int array[100][2], int arrayHeight) /*Start of the Function Usage*/
  {   
     /*Sorts the Array elements into appropriate chosen sorting order - Ascending*/
     int swap, i, j;
     /*for(k =0; k< arrayHeight; k++) {*/
        for (i = 0; i <arrayHeight ; i++) {
           for (j = i+1; j < 3; ++j) {
              if (array[i][0] > array[i][1])  {
                 swap = array[i][0];
                 array[i][0] = array[i][1];
                 array[i][1] = swap;
              }
           }  
        }
        ("\n Printing in Asending Order: ");
        for (i=0; i<arrayHeight; i++)
        {
           for (j=0; j<arrayHeight; j++)
           {
              printf("\n %d ", swap);
           }
        }
     BubbleSort(array, swap);  
     }
     for(k =0; k< 2; k++) {/* These lines of code sort out the stored array 
  number into the appropriate order - Descending
     for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = i+1; j < 3; ++j) {
           if (a[k][j] > a[k][i])  {
              int swap = a[k][j];
              a[k][j] = a[k][i];
              a[k][i] = swap;
           }
        }
     } 
  }   
  printf("\n Printing in Descending Order: ");
  for (j=0; j<2; j++)
  {
      for (i=0; i<3; i++)
      {
          printf("\n %d ", a[j][i]);
          if (i==2)
          {
              printf("\n");
          }   
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: When you output `swap` in the second loop, it is always `array[arrayHeight-1][0]`.  Are you sure that `swap` is what you want to output here?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Here is a few advices for writing better questions. 1) Format your code. Use 4 spaces to get a correct indentation. As it is now, it's unreadable for humans 2) Explain your input. Explain you desired output. Explain your actual output.

Comment: OT: What is `swap` doing in the definition of `DisplayArray` ?

Comment: Also there is a lot of "commented out code" in the end. Why is that posted?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, ["it doesn't work"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: @JGroven Well i am using Swap as a variable to swap over the numbers into Ascending order, that for me is the only way i know. What would you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

1. of all declare the prototype of the function or write the function above the main
2. first call the Bubblesort and then call the DisplayArray function
3. i think the logic of the program is broken here

   ```
   enter code here
    //this is wrong code logically  !!!!!!!!!
   for (i = 0; i <arrayHeight ; i++) {
   for (j = i+1; j < 3; ++j) {
      if (array[i][0] > array[i][1])  {
          swap = array[i][0];
          array[i][0] = array[i][1];
          array[i][1] = swap;
       }
   }
   ```

   }

the looping done using j but it is not used anywhere in the program i think it is a mistake

Comment: Well that bunch of code is used to calculate and sort out the ascending order which late gets printed out.. i am not sure how else to structure my work